# Javascript to change periods to commas for SRT script

Tags: javascript, function, srt

I have an srt file that is over a hundred sets long. Here is an example:

```
<body>    
1
0:00:01.040 --> 0:00:07.680
Hello I'm calling for Brenda Smith. 
2
0:00:07.680 --> 0:00:12.880
Thank you for requesting to close 
your loan by phone. Is now a good time for you to

3
0:00:12.880 --> 0:00:17.680
access the internet and sign the loan closing 
documents with me?
```

I'd like to use some javascript to be able to change the period (.) in each beginning row to a comma (,) in all the lines that have a colon (:). But I'm not sure how to do that.

I know this doesn't work but I was hoping that someone might be able to help me get closer to a solution:

```
function myFunction() {

if(document.body.includes(":"){ // I don't know how to target each beginning line in the srt file

  var str = document.body.innerHTML;
  var res = str.replace(/\./g, ",");
  document.body.innerHTML = res;

}}
```

Comment: You need to escape `.`: `/\./g`

Comment: ok, thank you, I added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the entire srt can be loaded onto a buffer, a replace like this is one of many possible solutions -

```
var res = str
.replace(/:[0-9][0-9]\./g, (match)=>{
     return match
     .slice(0, -1)
     .concat(',');
});
```